# Laravel 5 image url is good but image wont show up

Tags: php, image

I have a problem. When I upload my image file to my database I get this URL: C:\xampp\htdocs\finally\laravel\public\images/IMAGENAME.jpg

After that my Article shows up but image itself is blank. It doesn't show any error that image is not here or someting it just shows blank square. What could be the problem ? This is my upload image code:

```
$data = $request->except(['image']);
$data['image'] = public_path('images') . '/' . $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
$article = Article::create($data, $request->all());
```

HTML:

```
            <div class="img2">
                <img src="{{$article->image}}">
            </div>
```

Comment: Would you please post the html that is supposed to display the image?

Comment: when you look at your network response in you browsers developer tools, what does the network response say when it tries to load the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `C:\xampp\htdocs\finally\laravel\public\images/IMAGENAME.jpg` is a system path, and if you want to display an image on a website, you should use a URL path such as `http://mywebsite.com/images/imagename.jpg`

Second, have you verified that the image is, in fact, being uploaded to that directory? When you use file explorer to browse to that directory, do you see your uploaded image?

Assuming you are successfully uploading your image, here's how I would do it:

The location of where you are storing your image is fine. Leave it in the `C:\xampp\htdocs\finally\laravel\public\images` folder. But change the database entry to store the image string as `images/IMAGENAME.jpg`. Here's the code for that:

```
$data['image'] = 'images/' . $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
```

Then in your view, you would display the image like this:

```
<img src="{{ url($article->image) }}">
```

This will generate a valid URL to your image. Does that work for you?

Comment: now it works but only with .jpg image files. How could I make it to work with .png files ?

Comment: Use $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension() to get the extension of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
public_path('images') . '/' . $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
```

by:

```
 public_path('images') . '\\' . $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
```

Comment: Thanks for help but it's still the same blank space. :/

Comment: If you print `{{$article->image}}` in the html it shows you the full image path?

Comment: It's shows like this
C:\xampp\htdocs\finally\laravel\public\images\buddy_christ.jpg

Comment: Well, if file `buddy_christ.jpg` is effectively located in that path, I would expect to be permission issue. The browser's developer tools return something?

Comment: I don't think that it returns the images folder. Because 'css' and 'sources' folders it returns so I can use my .css files but it doesn't show 'images' folder

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar situation. Got error when trying to open image url in another tab.

In my case My APP_URL was set till the root folder 
APP_URL=http://localhost/laravel_project

so i had to add "public/" after current value.
APP_URL=http://localhost/laravel_project/public/

Hence 404|not found issue fixed